# MongoDB/Java: Inserting Document in Sub-Document

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to add a document into a subdocument but it is not added.

This is the code:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("testdb");

DBCollection test = db.getCollection("test");
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
document.put("username", "user");
test.insert(document);

BasicDBObject document1 = new BasicDBObject();
document1.put("title", "test1");
BasicDBObject updateCommand = new BasicDBObject();
updateCommand.put("$addToSet", new BasicDBObject("test", document1));
test.update( document, updateCommand);

BasicDBObject document2 = new BasicDBObject();
document2.put("title", "test2");
BasicDBObject updateCommand1 = new BasicDBObject();
updateCommand1.put("$addToSet", new BasicDBObject("test", document2));
test.update( document1, updateCommand1);
```

The result is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5321c6b0c2e682dc2fb97774"),
    "test" : [
        {
            "title" : "test1"
        }
    ],
    "username" : "user"
}
```

As you can see test2 is not added and I can't figure out why :(

UPDATE: This is what I excepect the code to do

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5321caa63b81968cb5f23d8c"),
        "test" : [
                {
                        "title" : "test1"
                        "test"  : [
                                  { 
                                          "test" : "test2"
                                  }]
                },
                {
                        "title" : "test2"
                }
        ],
        "username" : "user1"
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your query document is wrong on that last line.  It should be something like

`test.update( document, updateCommand1);`

Comment: I want test2 to be IN test1 not next to it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to reverse the operation :

```
BasicDBObject document1 = new BasicDBObject();
document1.put("title", "test1");

BasicDBObject document2 = new BasicDBObject();
document2.put("title", "test2");
BasicDBObject updateCommand1 = new BasicDBObject();
updateCommand1.put("$addToSet", new BasicDBObject("test", document2));
test.update( document1, updateCommand1);

BasicDBObject updateCommand = new BasicDBObject();
updateCommand.put("$addToSet", new BasicDBObject("test", document1));
test.update( document, updateCommand);
```

Because you're updating the "document1" after it been used to update "document". Then the second update won't update the "document" as well.